# Как прибавить какое-то число к каждому значению ключа в списке?

Tags: python, словари, dict

Кратко. Есть ключ, его значение состоит из списка каких-то цифр. Как к каждой этой цифре прибавить, скажем, число 5?
    `dictionary[nums] = [1,2,3,4,5]`
надо:
я ввел число 5 и стало `dictionary[nums] = [6,7,8,9,10]`

Comment: может быть так?c=0
```for i in nums:
    nums[c]+=5
    c=c+1
print(nums)```

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае лучше воспользоваться генератором списков

```py
dictionary = [i+5 for i in range(1, 6)]
print(dictionary) #output: [6,7,8,9,10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант

```
dictionary = [1,2,3,4,5]
input = 5  // Введённое Вами число(для примера)
dictionary1 = []
for nums in dictionary:
    number = nums * input
    dictionary1.append(number)

print(dictionary1)
```